# Force dependency to compile using a Makefile

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I compile a project using a Makefile. Somehow (after reading a lot about Makefiles), I can't solve the following problem:

I have a main file `edu.tex` and a file `edu-tut.tex`, which is imported to `edu.tex` using `\input{edu-tut.tex}`. So `edu.pdf` depends on `edu.tex` and `edu-tut.tex`.

If `edu-tut.tex` is edited, another Makefile in the subdirectory `doc/` is called, which creates a lot of figures.

Summarized, that's how it should work if I want to build `edu.pdf`:

- `edu.tex` edited: compile `edu.tex`
- `edu-tut.tex`edited: call the Makefile inside `doc/` and then compile `edu.tex`

That's an excerpt of my current state, but it doesn't work:

```
all: edu.pdf

edu.pdf: edu-tut.tex edu.tex
    [build edu.pdf -- this works!]

edu-tut.tex:
    make -C doc/
```

I hope this is comprehensible. I am a layman to Makefiles ...

Comment: It would be really helpful if we would have some `.tex` files to work with, Herr 'Kollege' ;-)

Comment: Do you depend on the make file? Editors like texstudio are capable to automatically detect the master file (in your case edu.tex) and compile this, no matter if you are editing edu.tex or edu-tut.tex. If you need automatic compilation, there are automating tools like ltx2any which are capable of more complex setups.

Comment: @Christian: Usually I post a MWE. The problem is, that my project is already complex. As it seems to be a conceptional problem I thought the makefile is enough. Maybe somebody can explain it without a MWE? Greetings to the 'Schwarzwald'! :-)

Comment: @samcarter: Yes, I do. My project is quite complex and I need the flexibility of a Makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following (untested) use of a run-stamp file looks straightforward to me:

```sh
# Either some file(s) generated by "make -C doc" or some run-stamp file
EXFIGS = doc/exfigs.done

all: edu.pdf

edu.pdf: edu-tut.tex edu.tex $(EXFIGS)
        # Your build commands go here

$(EXFIGS): edu-tut.tex
        $(MAKE) -C doc/
        # If the above does not actually create $(EXFIGS), add:
        touch $(EXFIGS)
```

Notes:

1. If you copy-paste the above, make sure that indents are done with tabs.
2. `$(EXFIGS)` are supposed to be real files, so do not flag them as `.PHONY`.

Answer (score 1):

The day after I posted my question (and befor @ccorn's answer) I did some tests related to this question. And I think I found another (rather simple) solution.

The idea is to check the dependency to `edu.cls` inside `doc/Makefile`:

### Makefile in / (root directory)

```
all: edu.pdf

edu.pdf: edu-tut.tex edu.tex
    [build stuff ...]
    make -C doc/
    [build stuff ...]
```

### Makefile in /doc

```
%.pdf: ../edu-tut.tex
    [build stuff]
```

This seems to work as well.

Comment: This calls `make -C doc` unconditionally (contrary to the question), but that `make -C doc` figures out whether expensive recompilations are necessary. This approach is preferrable, and I often see it used in Makefile hierarchies.